# grep out load average from uptime

Tags: bash, command-line, awk, grep

what I want to do is take the command uptime, and get the load averages

```
$ uptime
07:01:30 up 20:29,  2 users,  load average: 0.32, 0.39, 0.54
```

I have a feeling this is something I can do with awk, but I am not quite sure how.
pls assist.

Comment: I went into man uptime and found the /proc/loadavg file, then did: $ awk '{print $1,$2,$3;}' loadavg 
0.17 0.19 0.29
which got me what I was looking for. I will still look at the responses, the variation is neat.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a regex with backreferences: i.e. find any sequence of characters (.*) but only at a point directly after *average:*

```
uptime  | grep -oP '(?<=average:).*'
```

Comment: A little space after the colon?

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/shell-scripting-bash-find-out-linuxfreebsdunix-system-load-average.html).

```
uptime | awk -F'[a-z]:' '{ print $2}'
```

Comment: Could be shorted some:  `uptime | awk -F': ' '{$0=$2}1'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `grep`

```
uptime  | grep -o 'load.*'
```

Also you can extract the three load average fields separately by

```
uptime  | grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+*'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with Bash.

```
up=($(uptime))
load_avg=${up[@]: -3}
```

Or if you're reading from `/proc/loadavg`

```
read -a load < /proc/loadavg
load_avg=${load[@]:0:3}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ uptime | awk -F': ' '{print $2}'
0.32, 0.39, 0.54

$ uptime | sed 's/.*: //'
0.32, 0.39, 0.54
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `uptime` will always output data with the format above, you can cut at `:` and keep the fifth group:

```
$ uptime | cut -d : -f 5
 0,24, 0,23, 0,23
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `uptime` will print the load averages last, you can keep only the last 17 characters:

```
uptime | tail -c 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Uptime [takes the load average from `/proc/loadavg`](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/newlib/proc/sysinfo.c#L130) (as you already mentioned in your comment), where the three numbers are 1-minute, 5-minute, and 15-minute averages.

So, a faster solution without involving `uptime` would be

```sh
awk '{print $1}' < /proc/loadavg
```

which would print you the 1-minute average, etc.

Answer (score 0):

just throw this into a `main.c` file and compile it with gcc or another c compiler:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double loadavg[3];
    getloadavg(loadavg, 3);
    printf("%.2f, %.2f, %.2f\n", loadavg[0], loadavg[1], loadavg[2]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```bash
gcc -o loadavg main.c
```

now just do a simple `chmod +x loadavg` and do a `move loadavg /usr/local/bin` and voila, if `/usr/local/bin` is in your path, you can now enjoy a loadavg command that returns the exact same format as the uptime command.

---

if you want to get more info about that `getloadavg` c function, just head to this link: https://linux.die.net/man/3/getloadavg

---

## quotation as of writing this answer:

### getloadavg(3) - Linux man page

#### Name

getloadavg - get system load averages

#### Synopsis

```c
#define _BSD_SOURCE         /* See feature_test_macros(7) */#include <stdlib.h>
int getloadavg(double loadavg[], int nelem);
```

#### Description

The **getloadavg()** function returns the number of processes in the system run queue averaged over various periods of time. Up to nelem samples are retrieved and assigned to successive elements of loadavg[]. The system imposes a maximum of 3 samples, representing averages over the last 1, 5, and 15 minutes, respectively.

#### Return Value

If the load average was unobtainable, -1 is returned; otherwise, the number of samples actually retrieved is returned.

#### Versions

This function is available in glibc since version 2.2.

#### Conforming to

Not in POSIX.1-2001. Present on the BSDs and Solaris.

#### See Also

[uptime](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uptime)(1), [proc](https://linux.die.net/man/5/proc)(5)

Answer (score 0):

Simple `awk` oneliner:

```
uptime | awk -F: '{print $NF}'
 1.97, 2.06, 2.47
```

Or without leading space:

```
uptime | awk -F': ' '{print $NF}'
1.89, 2.04, 2.46
```

Another option is to use bash parameter expansion:

```
echo ${$(uptime)[@]: -3}
1.79, 2.10, 2.08
```